# Influxdb not sorting by time (cannot group float and string types together)

Tags: influxdb, flux, influxdb-2

I want to sort rows by time. Below query is throwing error called `runtime error @9:6-9:30: sort: schema collision: cannot group float and string types together`. I do not want to group anything. This is why I use `group()`.

My query:

```
from(bucket: "plc-metrics")
  |> range(start: 1707288974, stop: 1709794574)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "PLC_Sim03e162698dc1aa4f-status"  or r._measurement == "PLC_Sim03e162698dc1aa4f-total_count"  or r._measurement == "PLC_Sim03e162698dc1aa4f-good_count"  or r._measurement == "PLC_Sim03e162698dc1aa4f-speed"  or r._measurement == "PLC_Sim03e162698dc1aa4f-operator" )
  |> group()
  |> sort(columns: ["_time"])
```

Screenshot of current data:
[image]